# PHP / PDO : SQl to find row which contains a string value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I try to make a request to find rows which contains a specific String value.

Here is an extract of my code :

```
// Getting motscles value
        $motscles = $_POST['motscles'];

        // Prepare a second SQL request to get all annonces posted by the user
        $result2=$connexion->prepare("select * from annonces where titre LIKE = '%".$motscles."%' ");
```

I have no result, and i think my request is bad ..

Comment: Remove the equals sign after the LIKE keyword; that's invalid syntax.

Comment: Oh, and you're currently open to [SQL Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/3396).  You appear to be something capable of using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/812837), so **do so**, or suffer the consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LIKE =
```

Thats not correct, it should be -

```
LIKE  '%".$motscles."%'
```

Check here the like wild-card usage

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 6):

In addition `@abhik's` answer If you prepare do it properly

```
$stmt=$connexion->prepare('select * from annonces where titre LIKE ?');
$result2=$stmt->execute(array('%'.$motscles.'%'));
```