# To assign tags for larger sentences?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have two strings about the size of 15 words. How do I search for these words to be able to automatically assign tags?

I considered that I saved texts into mySQL original, converted to lowercase, remove foreign characters (html, php, javascript, ...) and then use mySQL query `WHERE text LIKE %word%` ?

**How do I clean words?**

Comment: *"How do I clean words?"* - As in guard against SQL injection?

Comment: Not sure if this'd count as a dupe, but should link to anyways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/24206873/ - *How do I clean words?*

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your sentence breaks words apart only with spaces then we can split each word in to an element of an array.  Then you can loop over that array to search with SQL.

```
$words = explode(' ', $sentence);
foreach($words as $word){
    $word = strtolower($word);
    $query = "SELECT text from tableName WHERE text LIKE %{$word}%";
    //run your query, etc.
}
```

Comment: But please use a PDO for your query to get some SQL protection.

Comment: `split` [is a deprecated function](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php). Consider updating your answer with `explode` instead.

Comment: good call @sjagr, I also added a strtolower in there to illustrate where to manipulate the text before searching for it.